# Jquery Datepicket Suppress Year

Tags: jquery

I have a calendar that pops when you click in the text box. I an already handling a year, I don't want to display a year in the date picker calendar. Can you please suggest. Have code in jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/uwohez/1

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".monthPicker").datepicker({ 
        dateFormat: 'mm',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,

        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {  
            var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val(); 
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val(); 
            $(this).val($.datepicker.formatDate('m', new Date(year, month, 1)));
        }
    });

    $(".monthPicker").focus(function () {
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").position({
            my: "center top",
            at: "center bottom",
            of: $(this)
        });    
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why a simple `<select>` element doesn't suffice in this instance?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/uwohez/7/ </br> this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I think I just done what you were trying to do (http://jsfiddle.net/robattfield/M5PHP/). Since I see that I have to supply code with a jsfiddle link, here is the code:

**Form HTML code**

```
<form method="post" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Select a month:</legend>
        <label for="month_datepicker">Select month: </label>
        <input name="month" id="month_datepicker" />
        <button id="submit_month" type="submit" name="submit_month" class="button-turquoise">Show Daily Data</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS code**

```
.MonthDatePicker .ui-datepicker-year
{
    display:none;   
}
.HideTodayButton .ui-datepicker-buttonpane .ui-datepicker-current
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

.hide-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar
{
    display:none!important;
    visibility:hidden!important
}
```

**JQuery/JS code**

```
$("#month_datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: "M",
        beforeShow: function (e, t) {
            $(this).datepicker("hide");
            $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("hide-calendar");
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass('MonthDatePicker');
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass('HideTodayButton');
        },
    onClose: function(dateText, inst){
        var n = Math.abs($("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val() - 1) + 2;
        $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(null, n, null));
    }
});
```

Your requirements may slightly differ, but I think this may help. Feel free to correct me if there is anything wrong...