# JQuery datepicker, months year only on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

I have a question, quite similar to the one at: [year/month only datepicker inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502445/year-month-only-datepicker-inline)

The difference is that I am using the `input` version, rather than the `div`.
In the `div` case, the `ui-datepicker-calendar` is inside the outer div, and so can be accessed uniquely.
But with the `input`, there is no relation between the input and the `ui-datepicker-calendar` (or, not that I've found...)
Just to be clear, I cannot use the "global" `.ui-datepicker-calendar { display: none;}`, as I have other datepicker that is a full one (i.e., uses the days as well).
My code looks as follows:

```
$("#monthsYearInput").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "mm/yy",

    onClose: function(dateText) {
        if (dateText != "") {
            var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", "01/" + dateText);

            $(this).datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
            $(this).datepicker("refresh");
        }
    },

    beforeShow: function() {
        var dateText = $(this).val();
        var isPopulated = dateText.length > 0;

        if (isPopulated) {
            var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate("dd/mm/yy", "01/" + dateText);

            $(this).datepicker("option", "defaultDate", selectedDate);
            $(this).datepicker("setDate", selectedDate);
            $(this).datepicker("refresh");
         }
    },

    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month) {
      if (changingDate) {
        return;
      }

      changingDate = true;
      $(this).datepicker("setDate", new Date(year, month - 1, 1));
      $(this).datepicker("refresh");
      changingDate = false;
    }
  });

$("#monthsYearInput").focus(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
};

$("#monthsYearInput").blur(function () {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
};
```

It all looks OK as start, but then when the year/month has changed, the new date is populated in the input (desired), but now the calendar displays (not desired).

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?...

Thanks in advance.

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/OhadRaz/8z9M2/

Comment: If a value for date is not supplied to the [Date constructor](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1), it's set to 1 by default.

Comment: Thank you for that. But what does it has to do with the problem described?...

Comment: Nothing, it's a comment on the code, not an answer. That's why it's a comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could still do it with a css like in [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502445/year-month-only-datepicker-inline) that you've linked but targeting only that one datepicker

```
#monthsYearInput .ui-datepicker-calendar { display: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your code on JSFiddle so we can see what it is doing? I may have done something familiar at [Jquery Datepicket Supress Year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518787/jquery-datepicket-supress-year/23593093#23593093), but can't tell without a JSFiddle demo...

Answer (score 0):

OK,
I came up with some sort of a solution:

```
var superUpdateDatepicker = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;

$.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function(inst) {
    var ret = superUpdateDatepicker.apply(this, arguments);

    if (inst.id == "monthsYearInput") {
      $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
    }

    return ret;
}
```

While working, I am not happy with it.
It is too hacky, it is not clean, and I just don't like it.

Any better ideas?...